# Journaling Folder Size Utility

Tags: ntfs, mft

I have been fascinated with [Everything](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_%28software%29) recently. It is a very simple utility that can manage to find stuff incredibly fast on NTFS because it reads the [MFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Internals) and journal.

Is there similar utility for folder sizes? Almost every folder size utility I have used is incredibly slow with folders with many small files in it.

Comment: I think there might be technical reasons that make determining filesize from the MFT difficult.

Comment: Determine filesize from the MFT isn't like reading a signle attribute, like reading the filename and reporting it to a search window. By far the most time consuming aspect of the calculating folder size is traversing the directory listing. Optimizing a database to look for a file name is cheap. Harder to optimize is reconstructing the folder hierarchy then finding its size on the fly.